# Is this a Stack based memory

Tags: c

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

int main (void)
{
  SDL_Surface* screen;
  screen=SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
  return 0;
}
```

screen is pointer to back buffer for drawing which requires quite a bit of memory.

My question, screen defined like that is a stack based memory because heap memory would use malloc.    Since stack memory is limited, is above code is bad because it takes up a lot of the limited stack memory and it should use heap memory instead.  But this code is from the open source code and I assume they know what they are doing.

Comment: This is definitely heap allocated.

Answer (score 6):

Here, `screen` is a pointer to a dynamically allocated `SDL_Surface` structure, which itself has a member `void* pixels` pointing to actual pixel data. The pointer only takes 4 or 8 bytes of stack space, depending on whether you are on a 32- or 64-bit system, respectively.

SDL frees the main video surface when you call `SDL_Quit()`, but when you allocate a surface yourself using `SDL_CreateRGBSurface()`, you must call `SDL_FreeSurface()` to free the memory. You can also find the declaration of `SDL_Surface` in `SDL_video.h` for a full listing of its members.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing other than that pointer itself is allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Does SDL_SetVideoMode allocate any memory or does it return a pointer to something pre allocated?  In some sense, it really doesn't matter because (I would assume) this code is run and the process exits, in which case all process memory is returned to the OS regardless.

(Mind you, "memory is returned to the OS" is not quite accurate as each process has its own virtual address space, etc... And "returning" that memory just means any real memory formerly allocated to that process's virtual memory can be freely used elsewhere.)

Answer (score 0):

To enhance the understanding: It cannot be stack-allocated. The reason is clear - a function can only stack-allocate data at higher postitions (seen from the stack's point of view), i. e. at lower addresses (seen as memory addresses) than its own stack frame, i. e. as the position where the return address is stored.

This means that upon returning from a function, all memory it allocated on the stack must (and will) be freed.

If the function returns a pointer which then remains valid, the memory pointed to by this pointer must be somewhere in the "persistent" data space, very probably on the heap.